# How to extract the row with specific pattern from tabular data in R?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have german population dataset in big `excel` file where I am only interested in NUTS3 level population of German regions, here is the further specific document that provided by `eurostat`: [NUTS classification](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/background). However, based on `NUTS3` specification, I intend to extract the row with a specific pattern. In particular, I need to extract the row where its `country_code` like `de`+ count any three numeric or count any three combinations of numeric and character.

Here is minimal reproducible example:

```
structure(list(code=c(de1,de11,de111,de112,de11a,de11b,de12,de121,de27c,de3,
                  de4,de41,de411,de94h,dea,dea1,dea11,dea12,dec,Dec-01,Dec-06,
                  dee,dee01,dee02,dee0a,dee0b,dee0c),
           region_name=c(Baden-Württemberg,Stuttgart,Stuttgart-Stadtkreis,Böblingen,
                         Schwäbisch Hall,Main-Tauber-Kreis,Karlsruhe,Baden-Baden- Stadtkreis,
                         Unterallgäu,Berlin,Brandenburg,Brandenburg - Nordost,
                         Frankfurt (Oder)- Kreisfreie Stadt,Wittmund,Nordrhein-Westfalen,
                         Düsseldorf,Düsseldorf- Kreisfreie Stadt,Duisburg- Kreisfreie Stadt,
                         Saarland,Saarbrücken- Stadtverband,Sankt Wendel,Sachsen-Anhalt,
                         Dessau-Roßlau- Kreisfreie Stadt,Halle (Saale)- Kreisfreie Stadt,
                         Mansfeld-Südharz,Saalekreis,Salzland),
           pop_1980=c(2981,9131,3438,576,149,120,2368,49,114,...,...,...,...,53,16905,5178,589,
                      555,1063,364,90,...,...,...,...,...,...),
           pop_1981=c(1981,9172,3450,576,149,120,2380,49,114,...,...,...,...,53,16910,5170,585,
                      553,1060,363,90,...,...,...,...,...,...,)))
```

Here is my desired output (just manually clipped):

[image]

**Update**:

In original data, missing value was filled with `...`, I want filtered data.frame respective `...` will be replaced with `NAN` or `NULL`.

For respective pattern in `country_code` column, how can I extract the row where `de`+ counting either three numeric or both numeric and character? How can I make this happen in R easily? Any idea?

Comment: The answers should help with the essence of your question, but please note that the data example doesn't work. All the quotation marks are missing. And a few of your records were likely messed up (by Excel?) when something like `dec01` was turned into the date-like thing `Dec-01`. So you'll need to look after that somehow.

Comment: @ngm thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to find the row numbers that match your criteria:

```
 grep( "de[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}", df$code)
```

This will look for strings with "de" followed by a combination of 3 letters or numbers.

To extract from the data frame:

```
df[grep( "de[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}", df$code),]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to write the regex is: `de[[:alnum:]]{3}`. This means "a `d` followed by `e` followed by exactly 3 of any letter or number. The nice thing about `[[:alnum:]]` is that it is a little more robust with respect non-English character sets.

There are many ways to use the regex. Some possibilities (say your dataframe is called `d_f`):

```
# Base R
d_f[grepl("de[[:alnum:]]{3}", d_f$code,]

# dplyr
library(dplyr)
d_f %>%
  filter(grepl("de[[:alnum:]]{3}", code))
```

There is a nice summary of basic regex usage in R that you can always access by typing `?regex` in the console.